# How to loop over environment variables in windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

In windows, I want to loop over a set of environment variables like in this pseudo code:

```
set MYVAR1=test
set MYVAR2=4711
set MYVAR3="a b c"

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do (
   echo %MYVAR%s%%
)
```

for which I expect the following output

```
test
4711
a b c
```

How to change this example code to get it to work?

Comment: I suggest you to review [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
set MYVAR1=test
set MYVAR2=4711
set MYVAR3="a b c"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do (
   echo !MYVAR%%x!
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Perfect, it works! Could you recommend a page which describes this strange delayed expansion thing?

Comment: here : http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html and here : http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php

Answer (score 2):

One more way, parse the output of `set` command using the variable prefix

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set MYVAR1=test
    set MYVAR2=4711
    set MYVAR3="a b c"

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('set MYVAR') do echo %%b
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
@echo off
set MYVAR1=test
set MYVAR2=4711
set MYVAR3="a b c"

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do (
   call echo %%MYVAR%%x%%
)
pause
```